# Why can I connect to Mongo in node using 127.0.0.1, but not localhost?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ipv6

I'm connecting to Mongo using the Node library, and mongo is up and running on port 27017.

If I set my uri to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017` it connects, but if I set it to `mongodb://localhost:27017` it doesn't connect (times out).

I'm on Linux, and my /etc/hosts looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

My guess is it has something to do with ipv6, but I have *very* little understanding of ipv6 to be honest. Can someone explain what's happening here, and if I should do something differently to be able to connect to localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, it seems that localhost resolves to IPv6 address `::1` and not `127.0.0.1`.

You can keep using `127.0.0.1` or another option would be [changing the address `mongod` service binds to](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/), for instance, `::1` (you can bind to IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time).