# Cannot run my nodeJS app using localhost but it connects when I use an IP Address instead. What is the difference between these two addresses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect my mongoDB database to my app.js server but it says:
[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Li9.png)

But it works when I change this line

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wikiDB');
```

instead of:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB')
```

I was expected the server to be connected to database. Even though the database server was running it could not connect successfully.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/73133094/3001761?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881